# How to make custom speech recognition in python?

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition

I tried out following code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
   text = r.recognize_google(audio)
   print("You said: {}".format(text))
except:
   print("Sorry")
```

This code works fine and print whatever i say.

But i want something like:

`If someone says: i want to create a new article / create a new article /create article....`

something like that

Then i want to get output like:

`create a new article`

Basically i want to know how to do this(steps) or what modules can help me.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code @Nitin Singhal

```
import speech_recognition as sr
#Speech Recognition Module

r = sr.Recognizer()
#Initializing r as a Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise
    print("Say Something")
    audio = r.listen(source)
#Gets the Audio Input
    
try:
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    text = text.lower()
    print("You said: {}".format(text))
#Recognizes the speech(Intenet required)
    
    if text == "i want to create a new article" or "create a new article" or "create article":
        print("Create new article")
#Displays the desired output

except:
    print("Sorry")
#In case any error, prints this
```

You can give as many as statements like I gave under the `if` statement. This gives the desired output.